# I'm getting a ''Expected ":" Pylance error and i dont know what i did wrong

Tags: python

This is the code. I know  that the "question" variables are useless, but that's how i like to do it.
I was supposed to make a pay computation program that asks for input about hours worked and rate of pay and pay 1.5 times the rate for hours worked above 40.

```
question = ('How many hours have you worked this month ?\n')
question1 = ("What's the rate of pay ?\n")

hrs  = input(question)
rate = input(question1)

if hrs > 40 :

    pay = (hrs-40) * (float(rate) * 1.5)
    print ('Your payment is ', pay + 'dollars.')


else hrs < 40 :
      
    pay = hrs*rate
    print ('Your payment is ', pay + 'dollars.')
```

I tried to nest it a different way and googled python debugger, but nothing helped. Please tell me how to fix this error and where my mistake is so that i can learn. Thank you !

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Its ''Expected ":" Pylance error line 13 col 6

Comment: `input()` evaluates to a `string` data type in Python, so you might want to covert it to a `int` or `float` first. In addition, `else` cannot take conditions.

Comment: `else` doesn't take a condition. Did you mean `elif`?

Comment: I know about elif and i used it first but it didnt work. I removed the condition and it worked also i managed to make it work with elif so thank you for your input!

Comment: What if the hours are 40?

Comment: Seems a bit unfair that if someone works for 41 hours you only pay them for 1 hour!

Comment: @NewbieCoder1234 - Just a heads up, your ‘accepted’ answer is completely wrong.  Try it yourself.

Comment: @S3DEV It used the code in the question as a base. It fixed the obvious errors, not he logical ones. Those are the same as in the question and to be fair they were not asked about. The question (as I see it) is about the error on the `else` which to me is a "typo"

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes the problem was the typo "else" instead of "elif" i resolved the other problems on my own and fixed the logical ones. I'm still thankful to the guy for pointing it out since it helped me fix it.

Comment: For the record, it shouldn't be `elif` at all. It should be `else`, simply without a condition. Also, the answer shows to convert `rate` to an integer which is wrong as you seem to treat it as a float. The correct thing to do would be `hrs  = float(input(question)) ; rate = float(input(question1))`. Also, in the `if` you only count the extra hours. So you don't even need an `else` at all. Simply calculate the base pay, and then in case of extra hours, add that

Comment: @Tomerikoo, youre right thats how i fixed it and I also added "try" and "except" so if the input typed is not a number it prints "Please enter a number" and i also fixed my math which was completely wrong since i was only paying for the hours above 40.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hope following code will help you.

```
question = ('How many hours have you worked this month ?\n')
question1 = ("What's the rate of pay ?\n")

hrs  = input(question)
rate = input(question1)

hrs = int(hrs)
rate = int(rate)

if hrs > 40 :
    pay = (hrs-40) * (float(rate) * 1.5)
    print ('Your payment is ', str(pay) + 'dollars.')

elif hrs < 40:
    pay = hrs*rate
    print ('Your payment is ', str(pay) + 'dollars.')
```

keep in mind that, input() will always return string datatype, and you have to convert into the int for arithmatic operation,

Wherenver you try to concat string, then you have to convert int to string

Comment: Yes it helped me a lot. The first time i tried with elif it didnt work and now i understand how to use it. Also i didnt think of str(pay) thank you.

Comment: Anywhere in your answer did you address the actual problem in the qusetion which is the condition in the `else`

Comment: Was this at all tested?  There is no catch for hours equal to 40, and as @kaya3 mentions, overtime work does not include base hours.  The calculation is completely wrong.  (Downvoted)

Comment: @S3DEV Yes, its all tested now, but it will be useful try catch if user input not int value, but our intent to be solve query.